# Do plastics impact health in adults?

Tags: plastic

I started drinking from a glass water bottle to reduce my exposure but I don't have any actual numbers to know how much impact it actually has to try and work out and what steps are worth taking to reduce exposure?

Do the chemicals leached from plastics stay in my system for days weeks years or even life.
What is the risk of cancer?
what is the negative impact on performance cognitive, physical and sexual?

Comment: You might want to include your research on this topic.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?